# Convert a CSV to MySQL update statement in Bash

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

How do I convert CSV file to MySQL update statement in Bash? I can convert it to a INSERT statement, but I want to convert it to update statement and add it to an existing row.

Comment: Please show some lines of your CSV file and the expected UPDATE statements for these lines.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you simply want to import a mysqldump you can use mysqlimport. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html for more information.

Comment: This. Also: MySQL can handle CSV files natively.

Comment: how do I convert CSV file into and UPDATE statement not INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

Import the csv in a new table.
update the main table with the new data.
remove the new table

Comment: Is the creation of a new table even necessary? I would say the [CSV storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/csv-storage-engine.html) would take care of that.

Comment: if you use CSV Engine you must copy the csv file to the server to access it. So you must have all permissions. its a real good idea.

Comment: Hm, right. I somehow blindly assumed .csv and database installation were residing on the same machine.